# Proxy keeps changing to 127.0.0.1:8118 automaticaly

Tags: windows-10, proxy

It seems that my proxy is always changing automatically randomly. If I disable manual proxy configuration it turns on again.
I've tried to delete some registry keys but the same keys appear again.

The 3 keys I tried to delete are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\MigrateProxy

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable (which is always set to 0)

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer (which has the 127.0.0.1:8118 IP)
```

It's really annoying that this is happening and it didn't do this back when I had Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. Only started doing this a few weeks after the free upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Can you check `netstat -a` or Resource Monitor (`resmon.exe`) to see what is listening on port 8118? Of course, if it *is* malware, it might be stealthed against those tools.

Comment: I would definitely run a malware scan as anytime I've  found proxy being enabled automatically it's been due to malware.

Comment: @CBHacking I've disabled the manual proxy a few moments ago so it's not on at the moment. I tried to manually turn it on but it doesn't seem to do anything that way. netstat -a doesn't show up any 8118 ports, maybe because I was the one to turn on the proxy. If you have any suggestions on how to get it work to see what is listening on that port that would be amazing, otherwise i'll have to wait for it to automatically turn on again.

Comment: @netniV I've tried malwarebytes and adwcleaner, none of them said anything about proxy's whatsoever, should i try another program? If so, which one?

Comment: Hold on. To clarify, are you saying that the 8118 proxy is your own program, and is legitimate, and the problem is just that the OS keeps configuring itself to use it even though it shouldn't? You tagged this as "virus" so I figured you thought the proxy itself was malicious. Whether you tell the OS to use a given proxy or not has nothing to do with whether the proxy listener is running.

Comment: @CBHacking Not, not at all, is that my English is very limited to explain things with clarity.  When i said " turn it on" i meant turn on the proxy manually in internet settings to test what you told me to do, but it seems that it didn't work that way. So i'll have to wait for the virus or malware to "attack"  again and reactivate the proxy by itself so i can see what the 8118 ports is listening to.

Comment: Port 8118 is typically associated with Privoxy, a filtering proxy suitable for blocking ads and whatnot. IIRC it was also used with Tor.

Comment: To clarify, since you admit your English is limited, does "_I've tried malwarebytes and adwcleaner, **none of them said anything about proxy's whatsoever**_" mean they found _nothing to complain about_ or that there _were some complaints_, just not _specifically_ about proxies? If the second option is the case, it seems quite plausible that the warning won't be that specific.

Answer (score 3):

Please check if any default url setup in below registry path

Left Pan

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\iphlpsvc\Parameters\ProxyMgr
```

Right Pan

```
AutoConfigUrl
```

If any default url setup, delete that and it should work.

Another option is simply copy the proxy URL which is being turned on automatically and search the same in the regedit, check where else the url is being used, delete that and keep the parameter value as blank and save and restart.

I tried many options changing ProxyEnabled to 0 and others but this one helped to get rid of the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can start by trying to change settings as an admin.

1. Run Internet Explorer **as Administrator**.
2. Click the **settings icon** on the top right corner.
3. Click **Internet Options**
4. From there, go to **Connections Tab** and then **LAN Settings**
5. Uncheck **Use a proxy server for your LAN**
6. Click OK and you're done!

After, boot into safemode, and disable proxy settings from regedit.

1. Open **regedit**
2. Navigate to
   **Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
   Settings** in the left pane
3. Double click **ProxyEnable** and change its value to 0

Comment: I sure had the same problem and fixed it this way :/

Answer (score 0):

The only option working for me is to enable proxy settings per user with RegEdit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Change DWORD-key '`ProxySettingsPerUser`' to '`1`'

Since this is a system policy you can also try to just remove the key.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I know someone will be on this page looking for this exact issue and if nothing works for you like for me, I tried literally everything including the registry editor tweaks etc and all but still on every PC restart, it was back and it was so frustrating.

After everything, I just downloaded **Malwarebytes** and run a full scan and boom! That was the solution for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would not recommend anyone to run any executables without justifying what it is, and what it does. As written this answer is equal to spam.

Comment: As if Malwarebytes is my own executable on a git repo or something. Dude, it can't get any worse than some random program changing up my proxy. Well, this was the only solution that worked for me and nope, this isn't some spam or malwarebytes promotion

Answer (score -2):

Please post the key/value pairs in:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

My hunch is that you have a proxy script enabled. I think the key is usually "AutoConfigURL" within the Internet Settings. For example, you can use this key to direct the proxy settings out to a .cgi file on the network to determine proxy settings - rather than using an explicit URL for the proxy. If this is the case, it may be malicious if there is no justification for the script settings.